# Write tests that rely on `IntersectionObserver` calls

Tags: javascript, testing, browser, intersection-observer

I'm trying to write a test that asserts something when element is in viewport.

I'm using the [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver) API, and it turns out that the calls to the observers is done when the browser can make them.

So the question is, how should I approach such assertion?
Should I just wait *some* time? How many milliseconds is enough?
Is there an event to know when the browser finished calling observers?

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
// ... do whatever to make the code observe some elements
document.scrollingElement.scrollTop = window.innerHeight;

// Wait for observer to kick in (tried 1, 5, millis, 10 seems to work)
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10));

sinon.assert.calledWith(spy, dom.querySelector(selector));
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there's something better to wait for than just *some time*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, 
You should try to use `requestAnimationFrame`, but use it twice.

for example:

```
await new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(requestAnimationFrame(resolve)))
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked!
But it's actually `await new Promise(resolve => requestAnimationFrame(() => requestAnimationFrame(resolve)))` (arrow function in the first call)